# Jquery selector is getting null

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am rather new to jquery and i am trying to do the below code

```
 var entityType = $('.unit-edit-entity_type input', self.$rowInEdit).val();
 var parentType = $('.unit-edit-parent_id select', self.$rowInEdit).val();
 $('.unit-edit-entity_type', self.$editEmptyForm).val(entityType);
 $('.unit-edit-parent_id', self.$editEmptyForm).val(parentType);
```

the `var` is getting the right value but after creating the jquery value using the class and set the value from the var the result is `''`

I cant figure out why.
Thank to all.

Comment: and as a side note, empty string is different from `null` , and both are different from `undefined`

Comment: Sorry there was a code there that i edited before posting the question and i deleted the dot.

Comment: and what happen now? Code tested or what?! Any chance you let us see relevant HTML code?

Comment: Still the result is empty.

Comment: what does , self.$editEmptyForm should be doing?

Comment: Without seeing your actual HTML markup we can just guessing you are doing something wrong, somewhere...

Comment: This is an mvc project with a edit view (hidden) that is getting the values and from then making the submit action. i can post the markup but i don`t know what to post exactly.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('unit-edit-entity_type', self.$editEmptyForm).val(entityType);
 $('unit-edit-parent_id', self.$editEmptyForm).val(parentType);
```

Should be

```
 $('.unit-edit-entity_type', self.$editEmptyForm).val(entityType);
 $('.unit-edit-parent_id', self.$editEmptyForm).val(parentType);
```

You  forgot a `.`

Answer (score 1):

Prefix `.` for **[Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)**

Change

```
$('unit-edit-entity_type', self.$editEmptyForm).val(entityType);
 $('unit-edit-parent_id', self.$editEmptyForm).al(parentType);
```

To

```
$('.unit-edit-entity_type', self.$editEmptyForm).val(entityType);
 $('.unit-edit-parent_id', self.$editEmptyForm).val(parentType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if self.$editEmptyForm is an element you should be doing;

```
$('.unit-edit-entity_type, ' + self.$editEmptyForm).val(entityType);
$('.unit-edit-parent_id, ' + self.$editEmptyForm).val(parentType);
```